# How can I retrieve the data of a model class from an fragment class using DBHelper?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, nullpointerexception

I try to display the user's personal information in a fragment but I encounter this error.

This is the Data Model class:

```
//A data model class with required fields.

@Keep
@Parcelize
data class User(
    val userId: String = "",
    val fullName: String = "",
    val email: String = "",
    @ServerTimestamp
    val dateRegistered: Date = Date()
) : Parcelable
```

My fun in fragment (I call this fun in DBHelper):

```
 private lateinit var modelUser: User

 fun successProfileDetailsFromFirestore(user: User) {

    modelUser = user
    binding.apply {

        textViewNameValue.text = modelUser.fullName
        textViewEmailValue.text = modelUser.email
        textViewDateRegisteredValue.text = 
        Constants.DATE_FORMAT.format(modelUser.dateRegistered)
    }

}
```

My dbHelper file (I call this fun in signInActivity).
A function to get the logged user details from from FireStore Database:

```
fun getUserDetails(activity: Activity) {

    // Here we pass the collection name from which we wants the data.
    dbFirestore.collection(Constants.COLLECTION_USERS)
        // The document id to get the Fields of user.
        .document(getCurrentUserID())
        .get()
        .addOnSuccessListener { document ->

            // Here we have received the document snapshot which is converted into the User Data model object.
            val user = document.toObject(User::class.java)!!
            settingsFragment.successProfileDetailsFromFirestore(user)
          
            when (activity) {
            // Call a function of base activity for transferring the result to it.
                    activity.userLoggedInSuccess()
                }
              
            }
        }
        .addOnFailureListener { }
}
```

And I have this error after:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.myApp, PID: 26367
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.myApp.SettingsFragment.getBinding(SettingsFragment.kt:27)
    at com.myApp.SettingsFragment.successProfileDetailsFromFirestore(SettingsFragment.kt:58)
    at com.myApp.database.DBHelper.getUserDetails$lambda-2(DBHelper.kt:94)
    at com.myApp.database.DBHelper.lambda$0boddd8ULIEqNjDjzqKOq3lWihk(Unknown Source:0)
```

Comment: At which particular line of code does the error occur?

Comment: `settingsFragment.successProfileDetailsFromFirestore(user)` and
`private val binding get() = _binding!!`

Comment: So your `settingsFragment` is null, right?

Comment: Probably yes (?) .

Comment: Then make sure to be different than null.